# Is there any free, small, fast, thing for compiling ActionScript-3 Flex apps on windows?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, compiler-construction, development-environment

What I want is as small, as light and as powerfull as [this for C#](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)  development environment for developing my AS3 RIA's on my EEE PC. On Windows.

In general I need codehinting (at least like [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) has)
And UI designer-builder (as similar as possible to one I have in Flash Builder at work,.. at leat like [this](http://flexible.riaforge.org/) but for Flex framework 4)
Main point it should be eazy in use (user-friendly) and small in size.

Can anyone, please, help me in my search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum... http://wonderfl.net/ ? It's online though, so no features like code hinting and UI designing. Perfect for snippets however.

For an EEE and the alike, I'd just suggest Flash Developer + Flex SDK.

If you want an UI designer, then it has to be Flash Builder or the Flash IDE.

Comment: Flash IDE... I tried... Screen is to small resolutioned so not all menus fit... and it is quite not for Flex framework projects... Flash Builder is based on eclipse... it takes 60 seconds to lunch it... it takes 2 minuts to go into design mode... it takes even more to drag something out onto the screen...

Comment: Maybe it's your computer? Too old/misconfigured/fragmented... I'm using Flex Builder (eclipse based, too) and have no big complaints on speed.

Comment: @alxx Asus EEE PC T91M Win 7... My main point of this Question is search for something lighter than FB for such less cool PC's

Answer (score 0):

If you were on OSX , I would have replied Textmate , luckily there seem to be a Windows equivalent here:
http://www.e-texteditor.com/
it's not free but affordable enough. You won't have the UI design though , but it should look similar enough to the example you have provided.

Comment: I have e-text editor....  I do notknow how to set it up with Flex SDK, secondly no GUI builder.

Answer (score 0):

There is [haxe](http://haxe.org), small, light, powerful and on Windows. But it is not quite ActionScript, although language and API are similar.

Comment: my Q was mainly on mxml GUI builder with AS3 code hinting editor. And I really do not know grate GUI builder for HaXe (never seen one). I respect HaXe - grate language.

Comment: @Kabumbus FlashDevelop supports HaXe